# ggplot scatterplot, dots that get larger as values become smaller. Values within certain range should all have the same size

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, range, size

Let me show you part of my data:

```
df <- structure(list(No = 1:9, X = c(0.005, 0.011, 0.011, 0.011, 0.011, 
0.016, 0.023, 0.022, 0.029), Y = c(0.457, 0.166, 0.208, 0.212, 
0.226, 0.107, 0.029, 0.055, 0.026)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

I am now looking for a scatterplot that shows 'No' on the x-axis and the X-value on the y-axis. The dots shown in the plot are supposed to increase as the Y-values become smaller. Specifically, I want that dots within a certain range all have the same size:

```
    range     | size
_____________________
    1 - 0.15  |   1
0.149 - 0.10  |   3
 0.09 - 0.05  |   5
0.049 - 0.01  |   9
0.009 - 0     |   11
```

I already have the following code in R, which does most of the job:

```
plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=No, y=X)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = Y, size = Y)) +
  scale_colour_continuous(low = "darkblue", high = "grey", 
                      breaks = c(1, 0.15, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01)) +
  labs(y = "Y-axis", x = "X-axis", size = "Determined by Y", colour = "Determined by Y")

legend_size <- c(3, 5, 9)
plot <- plot + scale_size(range = c(11,1), breaks = c(1, 0.15, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01)) + 
  guides(
    color = guide_legend(),
    size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = legend_size)))
```

This is the resulting plot:

[image]

What I don't like about the plot is that it does not seem to be exact. E.g. the second dot looks like it is of size 3, whereas it should be of size 1 (like the first dot).
(If I specify more sizes in 'legend size' I get an error message.)
It would also be super helpful if someone could tell me, how to have different colors for each range.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for `size` to reflect ranges of values you have to make your variable discrete. To this end I use cut to discretizise Y according to your ranges and labels according to your wanted sizes. To use this new var in the plot I convert it to a numeric with values according to the dot size.

This new variable is mapped on `size` where by I use `scale_size_identity` which automatically gives me the right sizes.

As for the colors I use a discrete color palette which I construct using `colorRampPalette`. To get the colors in the plot I use `scale_color_manual`. Finally, to get one legend for both sizes and colors it is important so have same breaks, labels, limits, .. for both the size and color scale.

```r
# Sizes and Labels
sizes <- c(1, 3, 5, 9, 11)
labels = c(0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 1)

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

# Make Y discrete
df1 <- df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(df,Y1 = cut(Y, right = FALSE, breaks = c(0, labels), labels = rev(sizes)),
         Y1 = as.numeric(as.character(Y1)))

# Color Palette
cols <- colorRampPalette(c("darkblue", "grey"))(5)
cols <- setNames(cols, sizes)
cols
#>         1         3         5         9        11 
#> "#00008B" "#2F2F97" "#5F5FA4" "#8E8EB1" "#BEBEBE"

ggplot(df1, aes(x=No, y = X)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color = factor(Y1), size = Y1)) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks = sizes, 
                     labels = labels, 
                     values = cols, 
                     limits = factor(sizes)) +
  scale_size_identity(breaks = sizes, 
                      labels = labels, 
                      limits = range(sizes),
                      guide = "legend") +
  labs(y = "Y-axis", x = "X-axis", size = "Determined by Y", colour = "Determined by Y")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>